# AWS S3 Storage Gateway or Application services API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services

i want let users upload and download some files. So what is a differenece between S3 Storage Gateway and API Gateway in application services? which one should i use to let user upload and download files ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storage Gateway is for connecting S3 to your corporate data center. This is not at all what you are looking for.

API Gateway has a upload/download payload [size limit of 10MB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html). I recommend creating a service on API Gateway that uses a Lambda function to create [S3 pre-signed URLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html), for the purpose of allowing your users temporary access to upload or download a file directly to/from S3.

Comment: ufater upload i need create temporary access to download some files. Thx i will try read more about Lambda.